# SQL Server 2005 update query based on same table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have a table with the following fields: `ID_Observation` (PK), `ID_Grading`, `ID_ObKind`, `Data`.

I'm having difficulty writing a query to update some rows based on other rows within the table.

If `ID_ObKind` = 9 AND `Data` = 'No' then any row which has the same ID_Grading with `ID_ObKind` = 10 and `Data` = NULL needs to be updated to Data = 0.

I have about a dozen different cases where data needs to be changed depending on the value of Data for a specific `ID_ObKind` so need to nail this down. Each `ID_Grading` can have up to 120 rows, each with a different `ID_ObKind`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will work for you. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2eeaf/14

```
Update TheTable
   set data=0
 where id_grading = (select id_grading
                       from TheTable
                      where id_obkind=9
                        and data='No')
   and id_obkind=10
   and data is null
```

Comment: Can I ask a question about this table as it doesn't seem efficient to me. One row is added for every Observation with any type of data going into the Data column, be it text, integers or floats. There is validation on the web page to prevent the wrong type by observation kind. Pivot has to be used to output all rows into columns. Would it not be easier to set up as columns with the database controlling the correct data type for each column rather than leaving that to the client side? No need for pivot and querying would be simpler? I've just inherited this database and trying to understand it.